# Присвоение итераторов

Tags: c++, vector, итераторы

Предположим, у меня есть `std::vector<int> vec1` размера `n`. Также есть `RandomAccessIterator` `begin` и `end`, которые принадлежат другому вектору `vec2` такого же размера. Я хочу, чтобы `begin` и `end` стали итераторами `vec1`. Как это правильно сделать?
Грубо говоря, мне нужно присвоить один вектор другому, но у вектора, которому я присваиваю, я знаю только его итераторы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если целевой вектор уже содержит нужное количество элементов - то

```
copy(vec2.begin(),vec2.end(),vec1.begin());
```

Так все элементы вектора `vec2` будут скопированы в вектор `vec1` *на имеющиеся места*. Это то, что вас интересует?

Если элементы из `vec2` нужно *добавить* к `vec1`, то -

```
copy(vec2.begin(),vec2.end(),back_inserter(vec1));
```

У вас какое-то невнятное изложение. Сначала кажется, что вы хотите как-то переприсвоить итераторы, но потом пишете - присвоить один вектор другому.

Comment: спасибо, помог первый вариант.

Comment: Ну, если ответ устроил - помечайте как принятый и закрываем вопрос :)